# Scala: collection of similar yet different types

Tags: scala, oop, generics, polymorphism

What I want to to is to keep similar yet different types in the same collection. Currently, I'm doing this using polymorphism (code is simplified):

```
trait Item
case class DoubleItem(id: String, value: Double) extends Item
case class StringItem(id: String, value: String) extends Item
case class BooleanItem(id: String, value: Boolean) extends Item
```

Then it's possible to create a `Seq[Item]` and add instances of the three types to it.

What I don't like is the redundancy. Usually I would use a generic `Item[A]`, but from my point of understanding, this eliminates the possibility of using a single collection (since `A` in `Seq[Item[A]]` has to be a concrete type).

Is there a better approach?

(Btw: I want to avoid using an HList implementation or something similar that increases complexity).

Comment: Which redundancy? I don't see any simpler approach

Comment: case class Item[A](id:String, value: A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Item` is covariant in `value`, you might do this:

```
case class Item[+A](id: String, value: A)

// example usage
val seq: Seq[Item[Any]] = Seq(Item("foo", 1), Item("bar", true))

def findBoolean(in: Seq[Item[Any]]): Option[Boolean] = in.collectFirst {
  case Item(_, b: Boolean) => b
}

assert(findBoolean(seq) == Some(true))
```